# How can I increment a Windows Phone tile notifications counter with Push Notification (not knowing the actual counter value)?

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone

I am sending a XML with the "Count" parameter for tile update, and the tile is updating with that value, no problem here.

But I don't know how many pending notifications the user actually has, to increment. I see WhatsApp increments the counter immediately after I got a message. The only way to do this is to store the "unread" count in the server? I wouldn't like to do this because the user can: receive the notifications, disconnect, open the app (that will reset the counter), close, and connect to internet. When it happens, the "unread" count will be incorrect after a new notification.

(I'm using a standard tile for WP 7 compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a hint from the design gurus -- you might not need to show the user exactly how many unread notifications s/he has.  Instead, you could make the push notification simply set a visual flag that there are *some* unread notifications.  When the user opens the app, it displays all the queued notifications and resets the visual flag.  Like a knock at the door: once you go to the door, you're going to let in however many dwarves you find waiting there.

Alternatively, you could use [raw push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202977%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) sent directly to the app, and let the app locally update the count on the tile.

Comment: But that's not what I see in other apps Bobhy... And the raw notifications will only work when my app is in foreground